# Using Parallel with a sed command iterating over thousands of files

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have 100,000s of files that I wish to iterate the below sed command over:

```
sed -s -i -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' -e '1 s/^/>/g' -e '3 s/|*//g' -e '3 s/^/>ref/g' -e '1h;2H;1,2d;4G'
```

So far, I have been using a bash loop:

```
for i in read_* ; do
    sed -s -i -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' -e '1 s/^/>/g' -e '3 s/|*//g' -e '3 s/^/>ref/g' -e '1h;2H;1,2d;4G' $i
    mv $i $i.fasta
done
```

How can I use GNU Parallel to speed this up?

```
ls read_* > list.read.txt
parallel -j $cores -a list.read.txt sed -s -i -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' -e '1 s/^/>/g' -e '3 s/|*//g' -e '3 s/^/>ref/g' -e '1h;2H;1,2d;4G' []
```

I tried the above method where I create a list of files to iterate over and perform 10 jobs at once, however I get sed related error commands.

Comment: Interesting problem but you forgot to include the most important bit of information ... *"I get sed related error "* ... What are they? Please add those to your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
parallel -q -v -j "$cores" -a list.read.txt sed -s -i -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' -e '1 s/^/>/g' -e '3 s/|*//g' -e '3 s/^/>ref/g' -e '1h;2H;1,2d;4G'
```

- The `-q` option is necessary to quote special characters (spaces, `>`, ...) in the command arguments.
- The `[]` was causing the code to break when I tested it, so I removed it.  I don't know what it was supposed to do.
- I added quotes to `"$cores"` because variable expansions should almost always be quoted.  See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/4154375).  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find missing quotes, and many other shell code errors.